# Springboot/Hibernate: Configuration property is not taken from environment settings

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have a spring boot service that uses hibernate. Now I want to configure the literal handling mode, as my query contains strings and numbers and I don't want to have a mixture of literals and binding parameters. I know there is the following parameter

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.criteria.literal_handling_mode=BIND
```

We normally configure our services via environments, but it doesn't work for this parameter. I already tried a couple of variants like

```
SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_CRITERIA_LITERAL_HANDLING_MODE
SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_CRITERIA_LITERALHANDLINGMODE
SPRING_JPA_PROPERTIES_HIBERNATE_CRITERIALITERALHANDLINGMODE
```

Any ideas, how to properly format it?

**Update**

I just had a look at the configprops endpoint of my service an realized that the ENV setting is simply bound in a wrong way. That's what I get

```
"spring.jpa-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaProperties": {
                "prefix": "spring.jpa",
                "properties": {
                    "mappingResources": [],
                    "showSql": false,
                    "generateDdl": false,
                    "properties": {
                        "hibernate.criteria.literal.handling.mode": "BIND",
                        "hibernate.default_schema": "MY_SCHEMA"
                    },
                    "databasePlatform": "org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"
                }
            }
```

So the underscores that are needed for hibernate are interpreted as dots here. Is there a way to define the ENV setting in a way to prevent that?

Comment: First one in the three should do the trick..If u do logging in app what value you are getting ?

Comment: When I activate the queries I stil have mixed for some parameter the literals for others the ? for the bind parameter

Comment: how you fixed it ? . Do you have any update?

Comment: No. I didn't find a way to have it configured via environment variables. In the end, we added the variable right away to application.properties and created the release like that as it anyways doesn't make sense to change it afterwards.